# Eclipselink NoSQL embedded documents are Binary or run into an infinite loop while persisiting

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I have a Category Class:

@Embeddable
   @NoSql(dataFormat=DataFormatType.MAPPED)
   public class Category implements Serializable {

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Field(name="_id")
 private String id;

 private String name;

 @Embedded
 @ElementCollection(targetClass = Category.class)
 private List<Category> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

If I persist it, it runs into an infinite loop.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A class cannot be both an Entity and an Embeddable.  The target of an ElementCollection can only be an Embeddable.  You need two classes.  A RootCategory (Entity) and a ChildCategory (Embeddable), perhaps sharing a common class.  It does not make sense to have an id in an Embeddable, so perhaps have,

CategoryRoot (id, category), Category (name, children)

Otherwise, consider not embedding the children, but have a @OneToMany relationship.

Comment: Cheers James, I just want to maintain my data in a single collection. So Category is Embeddable too and the Children are embedded in that. But Guess the self type embedded objects can only be serialised. So I created Subcategories to n level.